# Javascript modal won't close when click outside of modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

so I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to set up a modal for a website that will contain my Nav. I want the modal to close whenever the user clicks outside of it, which is easy enough and plenty of tutorial show me different methods but all of them either error or don't work. For reference here is my html as it stands:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Joe's Cars</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d862ed6876.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Raleway|Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <button id="openNav"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </header>

        <div class="navModal" id="navModal">
            <p>Navigation</p>
            <button  id="closeNav">close</button>
        </div>

        <script src="nav.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
    var modal = document.getElementById('navModal');
var openBtn = document.getElementById('openNav');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('closeNav');

function openNav() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

function outsideClick(e) {
    console.log('outside click called');
    if(e.target == modal){
        console.log('if statement executed');
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
}


openBtn.addEventListener('click', openNav);
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeNav);
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);
```

When i click outside of the nav bar, the window click is called and the console logs it 'outside clicked call', however the if statement does not execute.  This probably something obvious but I've never used javascript event handlers before and google searches are coming up with stuff which is way beyond what I can understand.

Thanks all

Comment: looks like it is working here https://jsfiddle.net/c3vgLm5n/

Comment: In `outsideClick` you check if `e.target === modal`, but it's executed when you click anything but the modal.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald doesn't seem to be working for me when I click outside of the modal.. just when i click the button.. Maybe it's something to do with my browser

Comment: It's working in JS fiddle but not in any up to date browser I try??

Answer (score 0):

You should not do `if(e.target == modal){` but `if(e.target !== modal){`.

You should also change `openNav` to :

```
function openNav(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Otherwise it will open and close your modal when you click the open button.